# AngularJs check user with every request

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to identify a user with every request. 
Right now this is my `routes` file:

```
(function () {

angular.module('employeeApp').config(routeModule).run(run);

routeModule.$inject = ['$routeProvider'];

function routeModule($routeProvider)
{
    $routeProvider.when('/', {
        templateUrl: '../views/login.html',
        controller: 'authenticationController',
        controllerAs: 'authenticationCtrl'
    })
    .when('/home', {
        templateUrl: '../views/index.html',
        controller: 'homeController',
        controllerAs: 'homeCtrl',
        resolve: {
            message: function(authenticationFactory){
                return authenticationFactory.validateUser();
            }
        }
    })
    .when('/werknemer/:id', {
        templateUrl: '../views/employee/employee.html',
        controller: 'employeeController',
        controllerAs: 'employeeCtrl'
    })
    .otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/'
    });
}


function run(authenticationFactory)
{
    authenticationFactory.validateUser()
    .then(function (response) {
        console.log('validateuser');
        constants.firstname = response.data.result.Employee.FirstName;
        constants.companyid = response.data.result.Employee.CompanyId;
        constants.employeeid = response.data.result.Employee.EmployeeId;

    }, function () {
        $location.path('/');
});
}

})();
```

The `function run` uses the `authenticationFactory` that looks like this:

```
(function()
{
    angular.module('employeeApp').factory('authenticationFactory', authenticationFactory);

    function authenticationFactory($cookieStore,$cookies,requestFactory,$location,GLOBALS,constants)
    {
        var factory = {};



        factory.validateUser = function()
        {
            var vm = this;

            if($location.path() != '/')
            {
                var api_token = factory.getToken();

                factory.isValidToken(api_token).then(function(response) {
                    if (response.status != 200) {
                        $location.path('/');
                    }
                    data = {"api_token": api_token};
                    requestFactory.post(GLOBALS.url + 'show/employee/' + $cookies.get('employeeid'), data)
                });
            }
        }

        return factory;
    }
})()
```

But right now I receive the error in my console:

> routes.js:38 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of
>   undefined

What am I doing wrong?

--EDIT--

```
factory.validateUser = function()
        {
            var vm = this;

            if($location.path() != '/')
            {
                var api_token = factory.getToken();

                factory.isValidToken(api_token).then(function(response) {
                    if (response.status != 200) {
                        $location.path('/');
                    }
                    data = {"api_token": api_token};
                    return requestFactory.post(GLOBALS.url + 'show/employee/' + $cookies.get('employeeid'), data)
                });
            }
        }
```

Comment: `factory.validateUser` doesn't return the request promise

Comment: Even if I do that I receive the same error! See my edit.

Comment: Please refer to the documentation about [$q](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q) You need this to return a probise (from `factory.validateUser`) that you resolve/reject manually after the validation process

Answer (score 0):

Your validateUser function returns nothing if the if clause fails, the resolve mechanism always expects a promise to be returned.

Try adding this automatically-resolving promise after the if clause, to serve as an **else**:

```
var q = $q.defer();
q.resolve();
return q.promise;
```

Don't forget to inject **$q** (AngularJS's promise implementation) into the service.